# Different look of material with Mix Shader vs Mix RGB

Tags: materials, shaders

I am mixing colors and roughness of a *Glossy* shader through *Layer weight* node.

*Material:*

[image]

*Mix Shader:*

[image]

*Mix RGB:*

[image]

Why do the same properties used in two similar approaches give a very different renders? Colors more or less equal, but roughness difference is quite visible.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mix shader use a very simple method to combine two shader output. It doesn't guarantee any real material based on physic light reproduce. You are actually using **alpha compositing** rather than reevaluate a BSDF shader. See the example below.

[image]

On the left we use **Mix Shader** to mix the **Roughness** between `1.0` and `0.0`. Right we use real `0.5` value for a single Glossy BSDF.

You can see that the Glossy 100% reflection just blend into the rough one without any transition. This is totally impossible in real world unless a clear-coat is presented.

So if a single BSDF shader can do the job, don't try to mix other shader, just let it do the calculation and connect it to the output directly.

Comment: Great explanation! I always prefered mixing RGB's rather than shaders due to hypothetical performance, but now I see real reason here.

Comment: @SergeL There is the performance difference. Double any BSDF shader is actually almost double the calculation of a surface. They are expensive shader compare to mix shader and mix RGB node.

Comment: @SergeL if you're interested at taking a look at the implementation of [Mix RGB](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/gpu/shaders/material/gpu_shader_material_mix_rgb.glsl) and [Mix Shader](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/gpu/shaders/material/gpu_shader_material_mix_shader.glsl) as GLSL shader. The `closure_mix` is implemented in [`bsdf_common_lib.glsl`](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/draw/engines/eevee/shaders/bsdf_common_lib.glsl).

Comment: The OSL shader implementation for Cycles can be found [here](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders/).

Comment: @RobertGützkow So the mix shader is a linear interpolation of two shader closure output? And the closure contain `absorption` `scatter` `emission` `anisotropy` properties, and there is no **roughness** property left for an accurate glossy BSDF?

Comment: @Hikariztw Looks like that's the case for GLSL, but I'm not familiar with the implementation so there might be something that I've missed.