# Repeating image texture not repeated

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, uv

I am trying to use an image texture for this mesh, but the texture is not repeating on whole mesh.

How can I have the texture repeat (section 3) through section 2 (white for some reason)?

I made sure there is no duplicate mesh with white material and normals are correct.

[image: mesh]

First modifier: solidify, second modifier: subdivision surface. Swapping order gives same render image.

[image: modifiers]

[image: node]

[image: render]

I am trying to make a smaller example with just the mesh but I am getting a different problem. I just copied the mesh from my scene to another file and it looks like only inside of mesh is colored.

blue.png

[image: completely blue image]

[image: render with only problematic mesh]

What could be causing this problem?

Comment: Is the mesh well UV-unwrapped? Will the problem remains unsolved after applying the solidify mod then unwrap it? And better use **only one shader** in a material if possible.

Comment: @HikariTW Your first 2 suggestions do not work (even after unwrapping after applying all modifiers). You last suggestion use fewer shaders did work (https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbRoO.png). Is there any way to have the "same" material with translucency? (removing the mix shader and translucency makes the rendered image not have the white section (section 2), but no longer have translucency)

Comment: Can you draw a figure to show what you want that lil cup colored? You can mix color and connect that to Principle BSDF Color socket, transparency can be set using that node value as well. Mix shader is a naive approach to combine shader, avoid using it on photo-realism render: [Example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158685/different-look-of-material-with-mix-shader-vs-mix-rgb/)

Comment: @HikariTW Sorry. I linked wrong image. Working nodes (no white section at rim): https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyvrk.png. Not working nodes (has white section at rim): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgpuu.png.

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to achieve but what is wrong with a Geometry node > Backfacing?

Answer (score 0):

Still not sure what you want to achieve, but you can use transmission value for glass like effect, or if you don't like the effect then use alpha value (not recommended).

Here is the final setup:
[image]

Please be noticed that transmission will directly bound to color of Principle BSDF color, so if the color is too dense (like `RGB: (0,255,0)`), it will make the light difficult to penetrate the material, hence need a stronger light source. Or just lower the value to reduce the color dense.